# Saving UIImage to plist problems (SWIFT)

Tags: swift, uiimage, plist

Simply stated,
I can encode a UIImage into a .plist if that image is selected from a UIImagePickerController (camera or photo library) and then stored into an object's instance variable using NSKeyedArchiver...

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!) {
   let selectedImage : UIImage = image
    myObject.image = selectedImage
    ...
}
```

I can NOT, however, encode a UIImage into a .plist if that image is one existing in my app bundle and assigned to a variable like this...

myObject.image = UIImage(named: "thePNGImage")

...where thePNGImage.png lives in my apps bundle. I can display it anytime in my app, but I just can't store it and recover it in a plist!

I want a user to select a profile image from his or her camera or photo library, and assign a default image from my app bundle to their profile should they not choose to select one of their own. The latter is giving me issues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `UIImage(named: "thePNGImage")` would not be able to find an image in your app's _sandbox_. It would find an image in your app _bundle_.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a noob. I meant the app bundle and not the sandbox. As for how I store an image from the picker into a plist, I simply assigned the image selected by the imagePickerController's delegate method into an objects instance variable 

(func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!) {
        let selectedImage : UIImage = image
        myObject.image = selectedImage
.
.
.

That object is later encoded using NSKeyedArchiver. That saves and retrieves the images perfectly! (cont below)

Comment: It's when I want to assign a UIImage from my app bundle to the objects instance variable that I can't save and recover it. So when I do something like this... myObject.image = UIImage(named: "thePng")... it adds the image and works well until the app closes and restarts. Then the image is lost.

Comment: What does this have to do with a plist? If the image is in your app's bundle there is no need to save it anywhere; it's right there in your app's bundle, and always will be. Could you rewrite the question to explain what the problem really is?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need any plist. If you want to save the user's preferences, use NSUserDefaults (which is a plist, but it is maintained for you).

Second, you should not be saving an image into a plist. Save a *reference* to an image, e.g. its URL. That way when you need it again you can find it again. An image is huge; a URL is tiny.

Finally, from the question as I understand it, you want to know whether the user has chosen an image and, if not, you want to use yours as a default. The NSUserDefault could contain a Bool value for this, or you could just use the lack of an image URL to mean "use the default".

But in any case you are certainly right that it is up to you to recover state the next time the app launches based on whatever information you have previously saved. Nothing is going to happen magically by itself. If your image is not magically coming back the next time you launch, that is because *you* are not bringing it back. Your app has to have code / logic to do that as it launches and creates the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Still having the issue? BTW, I've confirmed your issue. Here's a workaround:

```
func imageFromXcassets(name: String) -> UIImage
{
    // Load image from Xcassets
    let myImage = UIImage(named: name)!

    // Write image to file
    let imagePath = NSHomeDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("Documents/test.png")
    UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage).writeToFile(imagePath, atomically: true)

    // Get image from file and return
    return UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)!
}
```

Given the name of an image stored in Images.xcassets, the method returns the UIImage after first writing the image to a file, then reading the image from the file. Now the image can be written successfully to NSUserDefaults just like images obtained from your imagePickerController.

Please note that the example isn't handling optionals like it should. (I'm an optimistic guy.)

ADDITION BELOW

Note on Leonardo’s response:

The originating question asks how to encode an image obtained from Images.xcassets via UIImaged(named: String). I don’t believe Leonardo’s response provides a solution for this.